# Replace new method dexlib2 failing

Tags: java, android, dex, smali

I am using dexlib2 to rewriting existing apk through one jar utility. I want to change one instruction with my own instruction. It is basically returning some object and I want to replace it with another method which is returning different object. It is able to replace method but when I have viewed updated dex, I can see next line with .local v1, manager:Lblah/KeyguardManager;

Code which i want to replace

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```

Code which should be replaced against above:

```
Manager mgr=Manager.getInstance(this)
```

I have used getInstructionRewriter method to replace it. It replace the method but I am not able to figure out how to replace ***.local v1, manager:Lblah/KeyguardManager; with .local v1, manager:Lblah/Manager;***

Comment: I don't really know but you can check this project to see if there is something similar there https://github.com/khaledblah/dex_tainting

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You can replace `v1` just like you said. To be sure, you can decompile a code which has `Manager mgr=Manager.getInstance(this)` in it, and see how it is in `smali` and then copy it in that file of your `jar` class. If it is not what your question is about, please add the lines of decompiled jar file you want to change (I mean the `smali` code of it not the `java` code).

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that `Lblah/Manager` exists in your apk.
If you just want to make this change in one `.smali` file and leave other files unchanged, that will be easy. You have to fine all occurance of `KeyguardManager` in this file and replace the call they make with corresponding call in `Manager` class. Then repackage your `apk` and test it.

If you have error in recreating the `apk` file or after installing new apk, then it may be some mismatches in the cahnges you made and you have to find out what is the problem. In this case, you can post the error here and we will see what we can do! :)